# Flash compiled Arduino code over Bluetooth

Tags: swift, arduino, ios-bluetooth

I'm using a Bluno (Bluetooth enabled [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)) from DFRobot and am trying to create an iOS app in Swift that will flash compiled Arduino code to it.

I can establish a [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) connection using the core Bluetooth library, and I found the Service / Characteristic that will allow serial communication, but DFRobot has not exposed a method for flashing the code in their manager class, and their documentation is a little lacking in this area.

I know that it is possible to do this, because they have an app called [BigBee](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bigbee/id1064370567?mt=8) that does it.

Does [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) (or something similar) have a Swift or Objective-C library that can be incorporated into my app? So far I haven't been able to find one.

If such a thing exists, how can I incorporate it so that it communicates over the CBCentralManager object I create in my app?

Comment: Could you please try to write on the peripheral object using the characteristic that you are getting from the services.